Gijgo Datepicker Date with two digit Year converted to 20th Century
I am using Gijgo Datepicker in my website, my requirement is to show 2 digit year, and I changed the format to 'dd/mmm/yy' which is working fine, but when I select a date i.e. 1 Jan 1990 and reopen the calendar again it shows 2090. Please see the example and suggest.


$('#Dateofbirth').datepicker({
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    format: 'dd/mmm/yy',
    maxDate: new Date,
    close: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(this).valid();
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gijgo/1.9.14/combined/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gijgo/1.9.14/combined/js/gijgo.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css"/>


<input class="form-control" type="text" id="Dateofbirth" name="Dateofbirth" >



